# How to prevent the arrays from conflict?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have 3 different variable-sized arrays. Simply one is 2D `char` array, and the other two are `unsigned int` arrays.

Let them;

```
char names[numberOfPeople][MAX_NAME_SIZE + 1];
unsigned int ages[numberOfPeople];
unsigned int weights[numberOfPeople];
```

Let the people have common names, so the macro `MAX_NAME_SIZE` is defined as 10 as preprocessor.
`numberOfPeople` is asked to the user, user enters it with `fgets` and after some procedure it is read to the variable.

It's OK to have VLA's but the function which gets the `numberOfPeople` variable's value from the user comes after the array definitions. So arrays are defined with initialized value of `numberOfPeople` before it's changed.

Now, the problem is; how can I allocate memory dynamically and afterwards initialize the arrays? I've read some documentation about `calloc` , but as you can see, the arrays are not pointer to arrays. So I couldn't find the correct syntax for using `calloc`. It returns to `void *`, how can I achieve this?

Do I have to define arrays as pointer to arrays? And the first one is a `char` array, does it matters?

Comment: why not put the declaration of the arrays **after** the `numberOfPeople` has been initialized?

Comment: There is no need for memory allocation here. Just declare your arrays after asking the user and verifying the input.

Comment: So, no other suggestions at all?

Comment: No other suggestions, we are allowed to mix declarations and statements since C99, you should use it. Not only to sort out this little problem, but also to improve general readability of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the pseudo-code below will help you on your way.

Instead of defining arrays at compile time, define them dynamically at run-time.
Since, at compile time, you won't know the size of the arrays, just define them to 'point' to arrays, and worry about assigning memory to the arrays after their size is known (at run-time):

```
char *names;
unsigned int *ages = NULL;
unsigned int *weights = NULL;
```

I assume (since you didn't share this information in your question) that your code has storage similar to the following, used with fgets() to request "the number of people" as a string:

```
char tmpStr[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
int numberOfPeople;

printf("Enter the number of people: *");
fgets(tempStr, sizeof(tmpStr), stdin);
numberOfPeople = atoi(tmpStr);
```

Now that you know the numberOfPeople, allocate an array of name pointers, an array of ages integers, and an array of weights integers.

```
names = malloc(numberOfPeople * sizeof(*names));
ages = malloc(numberOfPeople * sizeof(*ages));
weights=malloc(numberOfPeople * sizeof(*weights));
```

To initialize the arrays, I (again) assume your code does something like a for loop, where you ask the user for the various array elements:

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfPeople; ++i)
   {
   printf("Enter name #%d: ", i);
   fgets(tmpStr, sizeof(tmpStr), stdin);
```

Now, allocate memory, and store the entered name in the names array.

```
   names[i] = strdup(tmpStr);
```

The 'strdup()' function calles 'malloc()' internally, allocating just enough memory to store the specified string (tmpStr); then it copies the string (tmpStr) to the allocated memory, and returns the address of the allocated memory; which is assigned to 'names[i]'.

Then get the age from the user:

```
   printf("Enter age #%d: ", i);
   fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmpStr), stdin);

   ages[i] = atoi(tmpStr);
```

Then get ...

```
...
```